# How to tell if reads are being redirect to MySQL slave on Rails3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, master-slave

**[update]** May be my use (or misuse) of the [seamless_database_pool](http://github.com/wbharding/seamless_database_pool) gem.

I just setup a master/slave setup on Rails3 using [seamless_database_pool](http://github.com/wbharding/seamless_database_pool). Does this mean that the reads are definitely NOT being redirected to the slave?

How can I check this at the MySQL level?
I was hoping `show processlist` would do this, but I'm not seeing any processes.

**[update]**

Running `show processlist` on the master displays the queries being run, so I guess the READs are not being passed to the slave.

The bin_log file just has the following (9's and x's added):

`/*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
\# at 4
\#xxxxxxx 99:99:99 server id 2  end_log_pos 106     Start: binlog v 4, server v 5.1.52-log created xxxx 99:99:99 at startup
ROLLBACK/*!*/;
BINLOG '
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
'/*!*/;
\# at 106
\#xxxx 99:99:99 server id 2  end_log_pos 125    Stop
DELIMITER ;
\# End of log file
ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */;
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;`

Thanks

Comment: What does SHOW SLAVE STATUS display on the slave machine? (see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-administration-status.html )

Comment: `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` is up to date and the master-slave communication is working. After some digging around I realized I needed to make a change in my configuration for [seamless_database_pool](https://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool), and all is well.. Thanks for your help, Isemi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the processes are too quick for you to catch on "show processlist". If that is the case, you might be able to turn on logging in my.cnf.

Otherwise, I understand that a slave MySQL is recommended to have binary logging turned on, and you can inspect that with the "mysqlbinlog" utility.

You would go to the directory where MySQL binlogs are stored (on Linux it's usually /var/lib/mysql or /var/lib/mysql/data), check the various bin files to get the latest - something like thisisyourbinfile.001723 - and just run mysqlbinlog on it. The output is pretty messy, but can be easily parsed with sed or searched with grep.

There are also utilities which will intercept MySQL packets at the network level, and display them on standard output. Most are based on tcpdump, and you actually need little more than tcpdump itself:
e.g.   http://www.megalinux.net/using-tcpdump-for-mysql-query-logging/

Comment: Thanks Isemi, I should mention that I do see the queries on the master mysql when issuing `show processlist`. I assumed it was being passed to the slave, but you've confirmed that I should see them on the slave itself. I've turned on the bin-log on the slave machine but all I see is 20 lines about the start of binlog. I'll update my question with this info.